# Xbox 360 not logging in correctly

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, xbox-network

I have an Xbox 360 and an Xbox One. After a few years of not using it I decided to play my Xbox 360 again.

After I set it up again I realized that my gamer score was not up to date, but I can't log in. I reset my password multiple times but it still said it was incorrect. Then by chance the password was skipped and I logged in, but after a while my internet went down and it asked for the password again.

Even after it updated the profile it didn't work and I can't redownload the profile - every time I try it says it cannot be performed currently. I double-checked and all of the information is correct, it just isn't able to download profile's.

The problem only seems to happen with mine; we did the same thing with another profile and it worked. Today I cleared the data cache but can't confirm if it will work until my grandpa comes home since he set the account up on his email and I keep trying with my profile and still nothing works except on my Xbox One.

How can I sign in to my account?

Comment: Is it an xbox *one*, or a pre-360 xbox? So it's the 360 that can't log in?

Comment: Punctuation and grammar are your friend.

Answer (score 3):

You may have changed your Live account password in those years, and possibly on some Microsoft website (i.e. not from your xbox).

Changing your Live account password online allows you to do things you can't do on a xbox... which makes the xbox won't be able to connect to xbox Live, telling you essentially that your password is incorrect.

Make sure your password:

- **Doesn't contain spaces**. The <kbd>Y | Space</kbd> key is grayed out in the xbox live password
  entry screen.
- **Isn't longer than 16 characters**. The 17th character will sound a "tick" just like the 16th one and the 15 others before it, but a new dot will not appear in the textbox of the xbox live password entry screen.

I cannot fathom a reason why changing your Live account password online, to contain whitespace and/or be longer than 16 characters doesn't at least warn you that your xbox won't be able to connect anymore - it's not like Microsoft doesn't know that the Live account is used on xbox Live.

Experienced on xbox360 - not sure if xbox 1 (one? or pre-360?) has other constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I had this same problem for weeks, what I did to solve it was I deleted my account, and then re-downloaded it, it took legit half an hour of loading but it thankfully worked and I could choose "stay logged in*